# How To make CSS Definitions work in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I have a CSS file where I put all my styles inside and whenever I define any code such as:

```
MYtitle{
color: brown;
font-size:19px; 
font-family:"Comic Sans MS", Times, serif;
}
```

Then I call it in my html file using:

```
<MYtitle> This is my defined Heading </MYtitle>
```

It will work in Firefox and other browsers but not in Internet explorer, it will not sense my styles at all.

Is there another way to define the above to also work with Internet Explorer? I'm trying to build a website that works in all browsers

Any tips or help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are so many web design crimes being committed here that I just... I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer will only style valid HTML elements, and that's why there's the [HTML5 shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv) for IE8 and earlier. You can work around this by calling `document.createElement` with the element name in JavaScript:

```
document.createElement('MYtitle');
```

[Here's a  demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/zHLuL/)

More likely than not, however, you shouldn't be using your own tag type. This renders your markup invalid and can cause compatibility problems, akin to those you've just experienced. A possible alternative is CSS classes instead, though they might not fit the bill entirely. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. This is one aspect whereby I wish other browsers would act like IE instead.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, I agree. I suppose, though, there's a problem when new HTML elements are introduced and people refuse to update. (Solution: everybody update!)

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick reply minitech.